# android unicode smile

Tags: android, xmpp

Основная задача состоит в передачи смайлов Unicode последовательности через Xmpp чат в строке. Есть список смайлов http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode Как сделать конвертор для отправки и получения?

Comment: А зачем нужен конвертер? Вроде бы смайлы по этой ссылке являются обычными символами Unicode, так же как буквы. И их можно передавать так же как обычный текст.

Comment: По ссылке кстати написано, что это устаревший список и более свежий находится тут: http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html